# (Android) OkHttpClient caching based on URLs (different caching for different urls)

Tags: android, caching, okhttp, cache-control

For Android Apps, is it possible to set different caching times for different urls using OkHttpClient?

for example, I have two urls:

1. http://www.example.com/getcountries.php
2. http://www.example.com/getnews.php

for the first url, i would like to set caching for 365 days:

```
Request request = new Request.Builder()
    .cacheControl(new CacheControl.Builder()
        .maxStale(365, TimeUnit.DAYS)
        .build())
    .url("http://www.example.com/getcountries.php")
    .build();
```

for the second url, i would like to set caching for 3 minutes:

```
Request request = new Request.Builder()
    .cacheControl(new CacheControl.Builder()
        .maxStale(3, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
        .build())
    .url("http://www.example.com/getnews.php")
    .build();
```

will it work? (with caching in place, debugging is difficult).

Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work but I think you want max-age and not max-stale. A cached response written at time *a* will be served until time *b*, a time that is derived from the response’s headers. The value you specify in *max-stale* is added to *b* to extend the lifetime of the cached response. The value you specify in *max-age* is added to *a* to constrain how long the cached response is valid.

https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-cache-control/-builder/

Comment: Thanks Jesse. I made the changes and so far it seems to work!